# Use data from an SQL query, but don't display column in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EDIT: If I use $colName instead of $colname, I'd have no issues. Stupid, simple fix.

I have a query pulling 6 columns from multiple tables. The final column is necessary to be used in a dynamic URL I'm generating, but I don't want that column to display on my table. How can I hide it/make it not show up? Is there a way to call the data, but not use it in my table?

Query ex:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, exTable.f as CID
FROM table exTable
JOIN <other tables>
WHERE stuff happens
```

Table (you can see that my header row will hide fine, but the content won't):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="header"><strong>A</strong></th>
        <th class="header"><strong>B</strong></th>
        <th class="header"><strong>C</strong></th> 
        <th class="header"><strong>D</strong></th>
        <th class="header"><strong>E</strong></th>
        <th class="header" style="display:none"><strong>F</strong></th> <!-- THIS WORKS -->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?
        foreach($tableData as $row)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($tableColNames as $colName)
                {
                    if ($colname=='CID') {
                    echo "<td style='display:none'>" . $row[$colName] . "</td>"; <!-- THIS DOES NOT -->
                    }
                    elseif ($colName=='e') {
                        echo "<td><a href='http://my.url.here/".$row[CID]."_Document.pdf' target='_blank'>" . $row[$colName] . " </a></td>";
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "<td>" . $row[$colName] . "</td>";
                    }
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Create two variables.  One will be an array of the column header names and the other will be an array of the field names you want to display.  Loop through each array at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: `$colname` should be `$colName`.

```
if ($colname=='CID') {
```

Comment: The elseif ($colName=='e') works fine at present, so that's why I'm confused about that.

Comment: @niclake I updated my answer once I realised what the issue really was.

Answer (score -1):

Stupid, simple solution: use $colName instead of $colname.